# Get status of all p-checkbox on form submit (Angular PrimeNG)

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

I have multiple checkbox in my form beside every field, checkbox data will not saved. I have to figure out all checkboxes are selected before form submitting. If all checkbox selected I will get true otherwise false. I need to do in dynamic way as I  have huge amount of field in my form. Given some portion of my html code...

```
                            <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
                                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-11">
                                    <span class="md-inputfield">
                                        <input type="text" pInputText 
                                    formControlName="sequenceOfTotal">
                                        <label>Sequence of Total(27)</label>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                                <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-1">
                                    <span class="md-inputfield">
                                        <p-checkbox binary="true">
                                        </p-checkbox>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Comment: can you pls share your code?

Comment: I added some html portion of my code. Here beside every input field there will be a checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't exactly understand your use case and how "dynamic" the solution needs to be, but as you're already using formBuilder, you could add a new formGroup called "checkboxes" in your form that would contain the value of every checkboxes (default value to false, Validators.required).

For example :

```
// HTML
<p-checkbox [formControl]="this.form?.controls['checkboxes']?.controls['cb1']"></p-checkbox>
<p-checkbox [formControl]="this.form?.controls['checkboxes']?.controls['cb2']"></p-checkbox>
<p-checkbox [formControl]="this.form?.controls['checkboxes']?.controls['cb3']"></p-checkbox>

// TS
this.form = fb.group({
    sequenceOfTotal: [''],
    checkboxes: fb.group({
      cb1: [false, Validators.required],
      cb2: [false, Validators.required],
      cb3: [false, Validators.required],
    }),
});
```

Then, when you need to ensure that every checkboxes are ticked, you can verify that

```
this.form.controls.checkboxes.valid
```

Of course, if you're currently using "this.form.value" to generate the data that you send to the backend, then you could either create a second form for the checkboxes or split your formGroup in two.

```
this.form = fb.group({
    data: fb.group({
      sequenceOfTotal: [''],
    },
    checkboxes: fb.group({
      cb1: [false, Validators.required],
      cb2: [false, Validators.required],
      cb3: [false, Validators.required],
    }),
});
```

And make the corresponding changes to your template / functions.

Answer (score 0):

@Beerbossa I did it another way, as I said I had huge amount of field in my form. I took an array and set array element as false in [(ngModel)] for every checkbox

```
basicCheckboxes: any[] = [];

setCheckBoxes() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            this.basicCheckboxes[i] = false;
        }
}
```

HTML portion:

```
    <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
         <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-11">
               <span class="md-inputfield">
                    <input type="text" pInputText formControlName="sequenceOfTotal">
                    <label>Sequence of Total (27)*</label>
                </span>
          </div>
          <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-1">
                <span class="md-inputfield">
                     <p-checkbox binary="true" [(ngModel)]="basicCheckboxes[17]"  
                           [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
                      </p-checkbox>
                 </span>
           </div>
   </div>
```

And Then finally at the time  of form submitting, I am checking all the checkboxes are selected or not

```
if (this.basicCheckboxes.every(val => val === true)) {
                console.log('All check box selected');
            }
```